# Spring JMS - DefaultMessageListenerContainer thread name suffix number limit

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I am using spring JMS to poll messages from aws sqs. In that JMS configuration I used DefaultMessageListenerContainer with consumer as 2-20. Application is working fine. But in the thread name : DefaultMessageListenerContainer-16623

The number value keeps on increasing. When I start the application 2days back it start with 1. Does it cause any issues.
Like connection pool shutdown.

I am not sure.I need support to understand this.

Comment: Hi there, please provide more detailed information to reproduce your issue~